# Ajax Update Product/OnePage Checkout Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, onepage-checkout, ajax

Since today i am experiencing a very strangle problem. Without changing anything, i can't update products (stuck on Please Wait...) and onepage checkout is stuck in step 2 (billing). Log files do not display anything and also no errors in console...

Magento 1.9.0.1
Any ideas, because with no errors i have nowhere to start.

Thanks

Comment: Any response from the request? Check out the Network tab in browser developer tools.

Comment: If you are on a slower server, try increasing your php timeout settings.